# Defining Two Workflows Using Using .filterWhen

Tags: project-reactor

I have an async predicate that checks whether a document exists in my DB. Based on whether it's present, I have two workflows. I want to achieve this in a single reactive pipeline:

```
Flux.fromIterable(docIds)
    .filterWhen(docId -> dbConnector.isPresent(docId))
    .flatMap(a -> workflow1(a))  //workflow1 is guaranteed to return 1 element
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> workflow2(rejectedDocIdHere)));
```

The problem I am facing is that there is no way for me to find `rejectedDocIdHere`. This can be solved by setting an `AtomicReference<T>` outside the pipeline but I don't really want to do that. Some other things that come to my mind:

1. Using a nested `flatMap` as:

   ```
    Flux.fromIterable(docIds)
        .flatMap(docId -> {
             return Mono.just(docId)
                        .filterWhen(dbConnector::isPresent)
                        .flatMap(this::workflow1)
                        .switchIfEmtpy(Mono.defer(() -> workflow2(docId)))
    })
   ```

Is there a way to avoid this nesting? I feel like I am trying to use `filter` for something it wasn't made - it essentially filters items out and there would be no way for me to find these rejected items at a later point in the pipeline. Anyway would like to see what the reactive experts think of this.

Comment: Where is the `rejectedDocIdHere` coming from? is it the same as `docId`?

Comment: Ah, sorry it's a flux, my bad. It's those items in the flux that were rejected. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I feel like I am trying to use filter for something it wasn't made

I'd agree with this.

I'd only use `filter` or `filterWhen()` when you definitely have no need for this element again. If you do, then my preference would be to `flatMap()` to a separate type instead, then perform your subsequent reactive operations based on that type:

```
Flux.fromIterable(docIds)
    .flatMap(docId -> dbConnector.isPresent(docId).zipWith(Mono.just(docId))
       //From this point onwards you have a type containing both the ID, and its validation status
    .flatMap(t -> t.getT1() ?
                  workflow1(t.getT2()) :
                  Mono.defer(() -> workflow2(t.getT2())))
```

Note that the above example just uses raw Tuples for brevity, but I'd always favour using a dedicated type in real-world use; I find it makes the code much clearer. You could of course condense those two `flatMap()` calls in that example into one, but then you get into the nested situation that you're trying to avoid, and it makes further extension of the reactive chain potentially messier.